# Problem with state machine that calculates the Greatest Common Divisor in VHDL

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, vhdl

I am supposed to implement the greatest common divisor in VHDL. The testbench and the interface were provided. However, every time I run the simulation, this thing gets stuck in state 6 (`q6`) and I have no idea why. 
When I look at the output for the test I can see it is completely different from the specifications of the exercise.

My questions:

1. Why is it stuck in q6?
2. Why are the wave forms not in snyc with the specification? How do I set `ack=1` only after reading `reg_a` and `reg_b`?

### gdc

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity gcd is
  port (clk : in std_logic;             -- The clock signal.
    reset : in  std_logic;              -- Reset the module.
    req   : in  std_logic;              -- Input operand / start computation.
    AB    : in  unsigned(15 downto 0);  -- The two operands.
    ack   : out std_logic;              -- Computation is complete.
    C     : out unsigned(15 downto 0)); -- The result.
end gcd;

architecture fsmd of gcd is

  type state_type is (q0, q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7, q8);

  signal reg_a, next_reg_a, next_reg_b, reg_b : unsigned(15 downto 0);

  signal state, next_state : state_type;


begin

  -- Combinatoriel logic

  cl : process (req,AB,state,reg_a,reg_b,reset,next_reg_a,next_reg_b)
  begin
    case (state) is
        when q0 =>
            --
            ack <= '0';
            next_reg_a <= to_unsigned(0, C'length);
            next_reg_b <= to_unsigned(0, C'length);
            C <= to_unsigned(0, C'length);
            --
            if req='1' then
                next_state <= q1;
            end if;
        when q1 =>
            if req='1' then
                reg_a <= AB;
                next_state <= q2;
            else
                next_state <= q0;
            end if;
        when q2 =>
            if req='1' then
                ack <= '1';
                next_state <= q3;
            else
                next_state <= q0;
            end if;
        when q3 =>
            ack <= '0' after 5ns;
            if req='0' then
                next_state <= q4;
            end if;
        when q4 =>
            if req='1' then
                reg_b <= AB;
                next_state <= q5;
            end if;
        when q5 => -- BREAK POINT
            if req='1' then
                if reg_a > reg_b then
                    next_state <= q6;
                elsif reg_b > reg_a then
                    next_state <= q7;
                else -- Equal operands
                    next_state <= q8;
                end if;
             else
                ack <= '0';
                next_state <= q0;
             end if;
        when q6 =>
            if req='1' then -- swap
                next_reg_b <= reg_a - reg_b;
                reg_a <= reg_b;
                reg_b <= next_reg_b;
                next_state <= q5;
             else
                next_state <= q0;
             end if;
        when q7 =>
            if req='1' then  --swap
                next_reg_a <= reg_b - reg_a;
                reg_b <= reg_a;
                reg_a <= next_reg_a;
                next_state <= q5;
             else
                next_state <= q0;
             end if;
        when q8 => -- SHOW RESULT
            C <= reg_b;
            ack <= '1';
            if req='0' then 
                C <= to_unsigned(0, C'length);
                next_state <= q0;
            end if;
    end case;
  end process cl;

  -- Registers

  seq : process(clk, reset)
  begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
        if reset='1' then
            state <= q0;
        else
            state <= next_state;
        end if;
    end if;
  end process;

end fsmd;
```

### Test Bench

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

entity gcd_tb is
end gcd_tb;

architecture behaviour of gcd_tb is

    -- Period of the clock 
    constant CLOCK : time := 20 ns;

    component gcd
        port (clk : in std_logic;             -- The clock signal.
            reset : in  std_logic;              -- Reset the module.
            req   : in  std_logic;              -- Start computation.
            AB    : in  unsigned(15 downto 0);  -- The two operands.
            ack   : out std_logic;              -- Computation is complete.
            C     : out unsigned(15 downto 0)); -- The result.
    end component;

    -- Internal signals
    signal clk, reset : std_logic;
    signal req, ack   : std_logic;
    signal AB, C      : unsigned(15 downto 0);

begin

        -- Instantiate gcd module and wire it up to internal signals used for testing
        g : gcd port map(
            clk   => clk,
            reset => reset,
            req   => req,
            AB    => AB,
            ack   => ack,
            C     => C
        );

    -- Clock generation (simulation use only)
    process
    begin
        clk <= '1'; wait for CLOCK/2;
        clk <= '0'; wait for CLOCK/2;
    end process;

    -- Process to provide test input to the entity in the testbench
    process

        constant N_OPS : natural := 5;

        type t_ops is array (0 to N_OPS-1) of natural;
        -- Change numbers here if you what to run different tests
        variable a_ops     : t_ops := (91, 32768, 49, 29232, 25);
        variable b_ops     : t_ops := (63, 272, 98, 488, 5);
        variable c_results : t_ops := (7, 16, 49, 8, 5);
    begin

        -- Reset entity for some clock cycles
        reset <= '1';
        wait for CLOCK*4;
        reset <= '0';
        wait for CLOCK;

        for i in 0 to N_OPS-1 loop
            -- Supply first operand
            req <= '1';
            AB  <= to_unsigned(a_ops(i), AB'length);

            -- Wait for ack high
            while (ack /= '1') loop
                wait for CLOCK;
            end loop;

            req <= '0';

            -- Wait for ack low
            while (ack /= '0') loop
                wait for CLOCK;
            end loop;

            -- Supply second operand
            req <= '1';
            AB  <= to_unsigned(b_ops(i), AB'length);

            -- Wait for ack high
            while (ack /= '1') loop
                wait for CLOCK;
            end loop;

            -- Test the result of the computation
            assert C = to_unsigned(c_results(i),C'length) report "Wrong result!" severity failure;

            req <= '0';

            -- Wait for ack low
            while (ack /= '0') loop
                wait for CLOCK;
            end loop;

        end loop;

        wait for CLOCK;
        report "Tests succeeded!" severity note;
        std.env.stop(0);

    end process;

end behaviour;
```

#### Test output

[image: Test output]

#### Exercise

[image: Exercise specification]

Comment: The best way to debug is to use the simulator. Watch the internal signals as the testbench is running. At some point your state machine will fail to make a transition that you want it to make...look at the internal signals and find the one that has the unexpected value. Trace the value back to its source. Fix the logic.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! This appears to be a homework question. As such, you need to show us your work so far, and explain which part of the question you're having trouble with. For future reference: Homework questions on EE.SE enjoy/suffer a special treatment. We don't provide complete answers, we only provide hints or Socratic questions, and only when you have demonstrated sufficient effort of your own. Otherwise, we would be doing you a disservice, and getting swamped by homework questions at the same time. See also [here](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/5120/7036).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you think the simulation is "stuck" in q6? Clearly, `next_state` is q5, and that's what will happen on the next clock edge. You just need to let the simulation run longer.

Your waveforms will not match those given in the example exactly — those only represent the general form of the handshake — and the squiggly lines about 2/3 of the way through represent an arbitrary amount of time, possibly many clock cycles.

Comment: True. There were other small details I had to fix, but the main reason why I couldn't see the sequence of the simulation was because I had to manually set it to continue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you want the HDL to do exactly what you want it to do, you will do these things:

- Make sure that your sensitivity list has only the signals that it needs. (clock and reset, and maybe an async reset.
- Large comparisons of signals should not be made (don't compare two large vectors, this will lead to large blocks of async logic being generated and will reduce speeds)
- In a state machine, include all signals that cause state changes in every state.

The main problem is probably with the sensitivity list.